# Is it safe to install windows from within another windows

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, operating-systems

I installed windows 8 PRO directly from within windows 8 Enterprise by mounting the iso image file and running the setup program. Now I have windows 8 up and running but now there is a folder named 'Windows.old' in my C drive. Can this method of installation cause any damage to my computer ?

Answer (score 1):

You're safe to do that.  It renames your original install to Windows.old with your documents, settings, and program files as a form of backup.  If you don't need anything from the original install, just delete the folder.